# Can't import robovm bindings

Tags: ios, binding, gradle, libgdx, robovm

I am trying to be able to put admob ads in my iOS libGDX game from RoboVM bindings that I found [here](https://github.com/BlueRiverInteractive/robovm-ios-bindings). I began at first following these [instructions](http://sam.mycube.co/2014/02/16/implementing-admob-in-robovm-via-mopub/), however couldn't even finish the first step (which is importing) because it still used the classic libgdx structure. Because the bindings now use gradle (as does the rest of libgdx), I attempted to import them as a gradle project. When I clicked 'build model' , I get the following error:

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'robovm-ios-bindings-master'.
```

> Could not resolve all dependencies for configuration ':classpath'.
>   Could not find com.github.jtakakura:gradle-robovm-plugin:0.0.10-SNAPSHOT.
>        Required by:
>            :robovm-ios-bindings-master 2:unspecified

I most definitely believe that this has much to do with the fact that it specifies the robovm 0.0.10 snapshot while i use robovm 0.0.14. Downgrading the plugin (which i figured out how to and can do) breaks the robovm launch project for libgdx so that's not an option. How do i make it so that this can work or at least find another way to include admob ads.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked into what that robovm gradle plugin was and found that the snapshot version no longer existed. I just deleted the "-SNAPSHOT" from the end of of the dependency string in the binding project's "build.gradle" and the project imported properly